# jade syntax error how to send json to js ?

Tags: javascript, pug

```
a(href="#" id="pickndroppoints" data-pickuppoints="[{"Id":"HGHD","Time":"2014-01-28 21:00:00.0","Name":"Beach Road"}]")
```

jade compile give systax error Unexpected identifier

Is there a way to do this ? I need to send json and based on it certain event is triggered using js

Comment: I think you may need to escape your quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your attribute value for `data-pickuppoints` is breaking at.

```
data-pickuppoints="[{"Id":"HGHD","Time":"2014-01-28 21:00:00.0","Name":"Beach Road"}]"
```

as you have double quotes inside the json data. make it like

```
data-pickuppoints='[{"Id":"HGHD","Time":"2014-01-28 21:00:00.0","Name":"Beach Road"}]'
```

or escape the double quotes

Comment: HI could you tell me how can this be escaped ?

.append($('<ul><li><a href="#" id="pickndroppoints" data-pickuppoints="'+ JSON.stringify(entry.pickupPointDetails) +'"\ data-dropoffpoints="' + JSON.stringify(entry.dropoffPointDetails) +'"><span class="place">'+entry.operatorName+'<span class="time">'+entry.departTime+'</span></a></li></ul>')).show();

Answer (score 0):

I would say, as jade parameter are regular javascript, that you only have to use single quotes so the value wont break :

```
a(href="#" id="pickndroppoints" data-pickuppoints='[{"Id":"HGHD","Time":"2014-01-28 21:00:00.0","Name":"Beach Road"}]')
```

But I am not on my computer so I cant test.